# How do I get flask to send a file on form submit?

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask

I'm creating a web application for an internship that send a docx document based from a template that contains data from a form. I'm using ajax, which allows me not to have to reload the page on submit and my back-end is in Flask from Python.

**main.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_file, request
import generator
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)

@app.route('/',methods=["GET,POST"])
def index():

    if request.method == "POST":
        template = "tplReceipt.docx"
        form_data =  request.form
        document = generator.from_template(template, form_data)
        document.seek(0)
        return send_file(
        document, mimetype='application/vnd.openxmlformats-'
        'officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', as_attachment=True,
        attachment_filename='invoice.docx')
        
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run(debug=True)
```

**generator.py**

```
def from_template(template,form_data):
    
    template = DocxTemplate(template)
    context = get_context(form_data)  # gets the context used to render the document
    
    target_file = BytesIO()
    template.render(context)
    template.save(target_file)

    return target_file
```

At debugging, everything is fine and my informations are filled, however my file isn't downloaded when I hit the submit button, why is that?

Comment: When you say debugging, did you step through your code? If you need a 5 min intro to the Python debugger... https://youtu.be/Fxkco-gS4S8

Comment: I did step through the code, I just think it's because when I send my information I didn't catch the post response

Comment: Hey, I have the same error, how did you handle this ?